# Mocked Use Cases in Ktor/Kotest/Koin/Mockk Not Working as Expected in Endpoint Tests

Tags: kotlin, ktor, mockk, koin, kotest

I'm working on a Kotlin Ktor project and encountering an issue with mocking dependencies in my endpoint tests using Kotest, Koin, and Mockk. Specifically, the mocked use cases in my tests are not being utilized as expected within the `userRoutes` function.

Here's a snippet of my test setup where I mock various use cases:

```kotlin
class UserRoutesTest : FunSpec() {
    // Mocking use cases
    private var getUserOffersUseCase: GetUserOffersUseCase = mockk()
    private var getUserInfoUseCase: GetUserInfoUseCase  = mockk()
    private var userWishlistUseCase: UserWishlistUseCase  = mockk()
    private var saveUserUseCase: SaveUserUseCase  = mockk()
    private var updateUserDataUseCase: UpdateUserDataUseCase = mockk()

    private val mockUserDtoService = MockUserDtoService()
    private val fakeUser = mockUserDtoService.randomBasicUserDto()

    init {
        coEvery { getUserInfoUseCase.getBasicInfo(fakeUser.id) } returns fakeUser

        test("GET /{userId} should return BasicUserDto") {
            testApplication {
                application {
                    routing {
                        userRoutes(getUserOffersUseCase, getUserInfoUseCase, userWishlistUseCase, saveUserUseCase, updateUserDataUseCase)
                    }
                }
                val response = client.get("/user/${fakeUser.id}")
                response.status shouldBe HttpStatusCode.OK
            }
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

When i debug the test i see that the reference to `getUserInfoUseCase` in the test environment (for example `GetUserInfoUseCase@92335`) differs from the reference within the `userRoutes` function (`GetUserInfoUseCase@717fd87c`). This leads to the test failing as it attempts to access the real database instead of using the mocked data.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insight into why the mocked instances aren't being used as expected in the `userRoutes` function?

I have tried to inject references with Koin

```kotlin
    private val testModule = module {
        single { getUserOffersUseCase }
        single { getUserInfoUseCase }
        single { userWishlistUseCase }
        single { saveUserUseCase }
        single { updateUserDataUseCase }

init{
        startKoin {
            modules(testModule)
        }
}
```

userRoutes

```kotlin
fun Route.userRoutes(
    getUserOffersUseCase: GetUserOffersUseCase,
    getUserInfoUseCase: GetUserInfoUseCase,
    userWishlistUseCase: UserWishlistUseCase,
    saveUserUseCase: SaveUserUseCase,
    updateUserDataUseCase: UpdateUserDataUseCase
) {

    route("/user") {
        get("/{userId}") {
            val userId = call.parameters["userId"] ?: throw MissingRequestParameterException("userId")
            val user: BasicUserDto = getUserInfoUseCase.getBasicInfo(userId)
            call.respondSuccess(data = user)
        }
```

same issue with Junit 5 tests:

```kotlin
class UserRoutesTest: KoinTest {

    private val getUserInfoUseCase: GetUserInfoUseCase by inject()
    val fakeUser = MockUserDtoService().randomBasicUserDto()
    val userId = fakeUser.id


    val userTestModule = module {
        // Mocking the UserDataRepository
        single<UserDataRepository> { mockk(relaxed = true) }

        // Mocking each use case with MockK
        single { mockk<GetUserOffersUseCase>(relaxed = true) }
        single { mockk<GetUserInfoUseCase>(relaxed = true) }
        single { mockk<UserWishlistUseCase>(relaxed = true) }
        single { mockk<SaveUserUseCase>(relaxed = true) }
        single { mockk<UpdateUserDataUseCase>(relaxed = true) }
    }

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        stopKoin() 
        startKoin {
            modules(userTestModule) 
        }
        coEvery { getUserInfoUseCase.getBasicInfo(any()) } returns fakeUser
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun tearDown() {
        stopKoin()
    }


    @Test
    fun `GET user by userId returns user info`() = testApplication {
        application {
            configureRouting()  
        }

        this.client.get("/user/$userId").apply {
            assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, status)
            val responseBody = bodyAsText()
            assertNotNull(responseBody)
        }
    }

    private fun Application.configureRouting() {
        this.routing {
            userRoutes(getUserInfoUseCase = getUserInfoUseCase)
        }
    }
```

UPDATE

Using userTestModule doesn't make a difference, it works just like injecting dependencies manually... No matter what I do, userRoute() always ends up with a different object than what I put in the test. It keeps looking for the user in the real database.
For now this is how my routes looks like:

```kotlin
fun Application.configureRouting() {

    routing {
        val createOfferUseCase: CreateOfferUseCase by inject()
        val getAllOffersUseCase: GetOffersUseCase by inject()
        val getOfferByIdUseCase: GetOfferByIdUseCase by inject()
        val updateOfferUseCase: UpdateOfferUseCase by inject()
        offerRoutes(
            createOfferUseCase,
            getAllOffersUseCase,
            getOfferByIdUseCase,
            updateOfferUseCase
        )

        categoryRoutes()
        userRoutes()

        get("/hello_world"){

            call.respondSuccess("Hello world", HttpStatusCode.OK)
        }
    }
}
fun Route.userRoutes(
    getUserOffersUseCase: GetUserOffersUseCase = get(),
    getUserInfoUseCase: GetUserInfoUseCase = get(),
    userWishlistUseCase: UserWishlistUseCase = get(),
    saveUserUseCase: SaveUserUseCase = get(),
    updateUserDataUseCase: UpdateUserDataUseCase = get()
) {

    route("/user") {
        get("/{userId}") {
            val userId = call.parameters["userId"] ?: throw MissingRequestParameterException("userId")
            val user: BasicUserDto = getUserInfoUseCase.getBasicInfo(userId)
            call.respondSuccess(data = user)
        }
//...

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)
}

fun Application.module() {
    initKoin()
    configureSecurity()
    configureSerialization()
    configureStatusPages()
    configureRouting()
}
fun Application.initKoin() {
    install(Koin) {
        slf4jLogger()
        modules(listOf(appModule, databaseModule, categoryModule, offerModule, userModule, authModule))
    }
}


val userModule = module {
    single<UserDataRepository> { UserDataRepositoryImpl(get(named("UserCollection"))) }

    single { GetUserOffersUseCase(get()) }
    single { GetUserInfoUseCase(get()) }
    single { UserWishlistUseCase(get()) }
    single { SaveUserUseCase(get()) }
    single { UpdateUserDataUseCase(get()) }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of the `userRoutes` function?

Comment: Done, I have edited the post.

Comment: I don't see any problems in your code. The problem may be in the test organization so can you try to use the JUnit framework? Also, please try to create a mocked instance of `GetUserInfoUseCase` in place just before passing it to the `Route.userRoutes` method.

Comment: Whole project: https://github.com/Lycan7hropus/FreshNearMe/tree/develop_tests

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.

```kotlin
            environment {
                config = MapApplicationConfig("ktor.environment" to "dev")
            }
```

Thanks to Aleksei Tirman, who gave me a hint on the Kotlin Slack to add this code line.

Working test

```kotlin
package com.example.features.user.presentation

import com.example.di.appModule
import com.example.di.databaseModule
import com.example.di.features.authModule
import com.example.di.features.categoryModule
import com.example.di.features.offerModule
import com.example.di.features.testUserModule
import com.example.features.user.domain.usecases.GetUserInfoUseCase
import com.example.features.user.domain.usecases.GetUserOffersUseCase
import com.example.features.user.presentation.models.PostedOffersDto
import com.example.plugins.configureRouting
import com.example.plugins.configureSecurity
import com.example.plugins.configureSerialization
import com.example.plugins.configureStatusPages
import com.example.services.MockUserDtoService
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.config.*
import io.ktor.server.testing.*
import io.mockk.coEvery
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.startKoin
import org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.stopKoin
import org.koin.test.KoinTest
import org.koin.test.inject

class UserRoutesTest : KoinTest {
    private val getUserInfoUseCase: GetUserInfoUseCase by inject()
    private val getUserOffersUseCase: GetUserOffersUseCase by inject()
    val fakeUser = MockUserDtoService().randomBasicUserDto()
    val userId = fakeUser.id

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        stopKoin()
        startKoin {
            modules(listOf(appModule, databaseModule, categoryModule, offerModule, testUserModule, authModule))
        }
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun tearDown() {
        stopKoin()
    }


    @Test
    fun `GET user by userId returns user info`() = baseUserRouteTestApplication {
        coEvery {
            getUserInfoUseCase.getBasicInfo(any())
        } returns fakeUser

        this.client.get("/user/$userId").apply {
            val responseBody = bodyAsText()
            assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, status)
            assertNotNull(responseBody)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `GET user offers by user id`() = baseUserRouteTestApplication {
        coEvery {
            getUserOffersUseCase(any())
        } returns PostedOffersDto(fakeUser.postedOffers)

        this.client.get("/user/$userId/offers").apply {
            val responseBody = bodyAsText()
            assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, status)
            assertNotNull(responseBody)
        }
    }

    private fun baseUserRouteTestApplication(block: suspend ApplicationTestBuilder.() -> Unit) {
        testApplication() {
            environment {
                config = MapApplicationConfig("ktor.environment" to "dev")
            }
            application {
                configureSecurity()
                configureSerialization()
                configureStatusPages()
                configureRouting()
            }
            block()
        }
    }
}
```